# How to add some filter based on "custom score" using FOSElasticaBundle?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, symfony4, foselasticabundle

I am doing a service to apply some custom filters to ebay results. For that I am using Symfony 4 and FOSElasticaBundle in the following way:

fos_elastica.yaml:

```
# Read the documentation: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/setup.md
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: 127.0.0.1, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        app_product:
            finder: ~
            types:
                product:
                        properties:
                                    name: { boost: 10 }
                                    tags: { boost: 9 }
                                    description: { boost: 8 }
                        persistence:
                                    # the driver can be orm, mongodb or phpcr
                                    driver: orm
                                    model: App\Entity\Product
                                    provider: ~
                                    finder: ~
                                    elastica_to_model_transformer:
                                        ignore_missing: true
```

How I am calling ElasticSearch from the Controller:

```
$results = $manager->getRepository(Product::class)->findPaginated($term);
$results->setCurrentPage($page);
$totalresults = $results->count();
$maxPerPage = $results->getMaxPerPage();
$maxPages = round($totalresults/$maxPerPage);
```

The above code is working fine but I want to improve my results using more weights and for that I want to use some extra fields like: vendorRating, positiveFeedbacks, negativeFeedbacks, neutralFeedbacks, vendorTransactions, addedTime, editedTime

If a term searched matches the title, tags or description I want to sort the results based in the following conditions: 
- The time that product was added to the database (more old product gives the product more score)
- If the product was recently modified it will subtract a bit of score
- Vendor rating and transactions, a high rating with a lot of transactions will give more score to a product that a vendor with high rating but few transactions

Also there are some cases that I don't know how to manage them yet because if I have one vendor with a rating of 5 stars and another with 4.8 stars is easy, I will have to show first results from the vendor with a higher rating but if I have the same example but the vendor with 5 stars only has few transactions and the second one has a lot more I should invert the results. I thought that maybe a better approach should add a new index called (for example) vendorLevel where I can calculate the vendor level based in their rating, positive feedbacks, transactions etc

I checked the documentation of FOSElasticaBundle in Github but I don't see an example about how I could implement what I explained, if someone could point in me in the right direction or give me a small example to be able to continue I will be grateful, thanks.